# I want to unselect the radio button after pressing the submit button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, firebase-realtime-database, radio-button

I want to unselect the radio button after pressing the submit button .And also I want to validate radio button how  I can do that the user must select radio button .
This is my code

```
 int? _selectedValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedValue = -1;
  }
//radio
 ///Option A
       
      child: RadioListTile(value: 1, groupValue: _selectedValue,
          title: Text(option1controller.text.toString()),
          subtitle: Text("Option A"),
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          onChanged: (value){
setState(() {
      _selectedValue=value;
      // if (option1controller.text.toString()==null) {
      //
      // }
});


      }
      ),
  ), 
///Submit button
                 
                      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){
                        // _selectedValue=-1;
                        final id=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
                        final ref=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Politics");
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
ref.doc(id).set({"id":id,"Question":questioncontroller.text,"Option A":option1controller.text,"Option B":option2controller.text,
"Option C":option3controller.text,"Option D":option4controller.text,"Correct":_selectedValue.toString();
questioncontroller.clear();
option1controller.clear();
option3controller.clear();
option2controller.clear();
option4controller.clear();
                        }

                      }, child: Text("Submit",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),)),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly provide dataType on `RadioListTile` to nullable int while you are using  `int? _selectedValue;`

```dart
RadioListTile<int?>(
```

Now when you like to reset or have to unselect state , assign null on `_selectedValue`. You can skip providing default value on initState.

```dart
onPressed:(){
   setState(() {
     _selectedValue = null;
```

Comment: Same issue happened. Any other solution??

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What you want to say?

Comment: create a sample widget from scaffold that will reproduce the same error